# AngularJS nested accordions with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I have a 4 level model, for which I need to create nested accordions. However I cannot figure out why when I click on a Child, all of the sibbligs open (or close).

I'm using ui.bootstrap. Here's the code I'm using (the short versión anyway):

```
<div ng-controller="ProgramasController as vm">
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="programa in programas" is-open="status.open">
            <accordion-heading>
                <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-minus-circle': status.open, 'fa-plus-circle': !status.open}"></i> {{programa.xrmName}}
            </accordion-heading>
            <accordion close-others="false">
                <accordion-group ng-repeat="tipoDeAtencion in tiposDeAtencion" is-open="status.innerOpen">
                    <accordion-heading>
                        <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-minus-circle': status.innerOpen, 'fa-plus-circle': !status.innerOpen}"></i> {{tipoDeAtencion.xrmName}}
                    </accordion-heading>
                    <div>
                        algo
                    </div>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `programa` in your `programas` is using the same `status.open` variable.

I think you want to switch to using an attribute of the `programa` itself like `programa.open`; note that you may want to initialize the field to false in each.

You will need to apply the same change for `status.innerOpen` and switch it to `tipoDeAtencion.open`.

Comment: Thank you Agent B :). You pointed me in the right direction. However I am totally new to Angular (this is my first try) and I get the model from a GET. How should I add the attribute to the model? Or should I include the attribute in the WebApi model and pass it on with the rest of the model?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction and I got it to work properly. You are the man Agent @Blaskovics.

Comment: Angular is model agnostic. If you are loading it from a GET (eg `$http.get`) then it will likely just be plain ole json (javascript object) which you can add or remove properties from as necessary (eg: `var obj = {}; obj.foo = "bar";`).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use property from the iterating object to handle the open status as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="ProgramasController as vm">
<accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="programa in programas" is-open="programa.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-minus-circle': programa.open, 'fa-plus-circle': !programa.open}"></i> {{programa.xrmName}}
        </accordion-heading>
        <accordion close-others="false">
            <accordion-group ng-repeat="tipoDeAtencion in tiposDeAtencion" is-open="tipoDeAtencion.open">
                <accordion-heading>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-minus-circle': tipoDeAtencion.open, 'fa-plus-circle': !tipoDeAtencion.open}"></i> {{tipoDeAtencion.xrmName}}
                </accordion-heading>
                <div>
                    algo
                </div>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

So each level of accordion-group and its items open status will be unique.